# TouchBegan/TouchEnded with Array

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have 3 arrays of nodes, each array with 5 nodes. The nodes in this example are squares.

I want to move them using touchesBegan and touchesEnded, saving which array the user touched and then the position of the finger when he removes from the screen. I already know how to do that, with a node.

My problem is that i dont know how to tell my code what array to move, since i cant use something like array.name to tell the difference how can i do such a thing?

For example, if i touch my Array1 he'll detect that its my Array1 and then when i remove my finger he'll do a SKAction to move the nodes inside my Array1.

I tried to use array.description but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sprite Kit provides convenient ways to access sprites in the scene's node tree, there is almost no reason to use arrays to manage your sprite nodes. In this case, you can add your sprites a set of `SKNode`s, because you can easily access the "container" that a sprite is in with `node = sprite.parent`. You can then iterate over the sprites in that container by looping over `node.children`. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
var selectedNode:SKSpriteNode?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scaleMode = .ResizeFill

    let width = view.frame.size.width
    let height = view.frame.size.height

    let colors = [SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.greenColor(), SKColor.blueColor()]

    // Create 3 container nodes
    for i in 1...3 {
        let node = SKNode()
        // Create 5 sprites
        for j in 1...5 {
            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
            sprite.color = colors[i-1]
            sprite.colorBlendFactor = 0.5
            sprite.xScale = 0.125
            sprite.yScale = 0.125
            // Random location
            let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(width)))
            let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(height)))
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
            // Add the sprite to a container
            node.addChild(sprite)
        }
        // Add the container to the scene
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

Select a sprite to move in `touchesBegan`

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
        selectedNode = node as? SKSpriteNode
    }
}
```

Move the selected sprite

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        selectedNode?.position = location
    }
}
```

Rotate all children in the node that contains the selected sprite

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let parent = selectedNode?.parent?.children {
        for child in parent {
            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI*2.0), duration: 2.0)
            child.runAction(action)
        }
    }
    selectedNode = nil
}
```

Comment: Thats nice. =) Its a smart way to get an group of nodes. Thx a lot!